# Listados en batch

Tags: date, batch

Mi objetivo es hacer una lista de todas los archivos que hay en una carpeta, incluidos los archivos que estén a su misma vez en una carpeta. También quiero saber la fecha en la que fueron editados por última vez.

Mi primera idea fue usar el comando dir y poner la ruta a la carpeta que quiero analizar. Cuando lo hize usé este código:
dir C:\Users\Garci\Onedrive\Escritorio\Prueba > Lista.txt

[image: Este es el resultado del código anterior]

Pero esto no me enseña el archivo que hay dentro de Car2 que es una carpeta. Pero tiene todo lo demás, es decir la última fecha de modificación
Después estuve buscando y encontré el comando tree con el cual hize esto:

tree C:\Users\Garci\Onedrive\Escritorio\Prueba /f /a > Listado.txt

[image: Resultado del código anterior]

Al usar este código me salen todas las carpetas y sus subarchivos pero no me dice la fecha de modificación.

Alguien me podría decir como conseguir mi objetivo. Lo ideal sería que pudiera poner la fecha en al lado de los archivos en el batch que he usado el comando tree. Gracias.

Comment: Ese comando no está en CMD (Al menos, no me he dado cuenta de ello). Pero en internet hay muchos comandos que no son de CMD oficialmente. A lo mejor encuentras algo. lo único que resolvería tu problema si vas a hacer un programa (pero no recomendado) es poner los dos comandos juntos. Algo así:
[Click Aquí](https://pastebin.com/wua3x7JW) Eso es todo

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una búsqueda recursiva tienes que usar el switch `/s`

```
dir /s C:\Users\Garci\Onedrive\Escritorio\Prueba > test.txt
```

Aquí puedes ver todos los modificadores del comando `dir` en Windows https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir